# Error with Maven/Scala: error: not found: type classOf

Tags: scala, maven

I have an existing Java application which I am trying to migrate to scala.
I have an abstract class defined like this

```
public abstract class AbstractHibernateDao<T, ID extends Serializable> extends
    HibernateDaoSupport implements GenericDao<T, ID> {

     private final Class<? extends T> persistentClass;

     // spring parts-----

     public AbstractHibernateDao(Class<? extends T> persistentClass) {
           this.persistentClass = persistentClass;
     }
```

the constructor accepts a parameter of type Class.
I then write a scala class which extends `AbstractHibernateDao`.

```
package com.worldcorpservices.core.dao.shares.hibernate.scala {

import com.worldcorpservices.core.dao.AbstractHibernateDao
import com.worldcorpservices.core.dao.shares.VolatilityDao
import com.worldcorpservices.core.domain.shares.scala.Volatility
import com.worldcorpservices.core.domain.shares.scala.VolatilityId
import com.worldcorpservices.core.domain.shares.scala.VolatilityImpl
import java.util.List
import org.hibernate.criterion.DetachedCriteria
import org.hibernate.criterion.Order
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions

class ScalaHibernateVolatilityDaoImpl(persistentClass : classTag[VolatilityImpl]) 
    extends AbstractHibernateDao[Volatility, VolatilityId](persistentClass)
    with VolatilityDao {

          ......
```

I build my app using maven, and here's my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
                <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
                <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
               <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
               <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
               <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>
...
```

Somehow, when I run `mvn scala:compile` I am getting this error

```
[ERROR]  error: not found: type classTag
```

I have tried to use `classOf`,but got exactly same error (`not found:type classOf`)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to input a **class object** (the object that represents a class) as a **type identifier** (the identifier of a class, consisting of its name and generic constraints in case of generic classes) . Just use `VolatilityImpl` directly, i.e. :

```
class ScalaHibernateVolatilityDaoImpl(persistentClass : VolatilityImpl)
```

This is unrelated to Maven, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to extend generic DAO to get a DAO for your class. Then you have to write something like

```
class ScalaHibernateVolatilityDaoImpl
    extends AbstractHibernateDao[Volatility, VolatilityId](classOf[VolatilityImpl])
    with VolatilityDao
```

Note that you don't need any constructor parameters, hence you don't need `Class` type. But just FYI, Java `Class` and Scala `Class` are in direct correspondence, so if you need a variable of type `Class<?>` (or `Class<? extends T>`) but in Scala you just write `Class[_]` (or `Class[_ <: T]`).

`classOf[T]` function allows you to get Java class for the type argument. `ClassTag` is related, but different concept, which you don't need unless you use an API which is `ClassTag`-aware, but this is not your case since your API is in Java.

Comment: Thanks, that has fixed it.